# Azure Application Insights, how to change daily cap by Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-cli

I'm trying to change daily cap for data transfer for all my Application Insights on Azure. Is there any way to change it for all of them?

I can't find how to do it by using Azure CLI.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the daily cap with the Azure PowerShell cmdlet Set-AzureRmApplicationInsightsDailyCap.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionName "Your Sub Name"

function Set-DailyCap {

    $AI = Get-AzureRmApplicationInsights | Select ResourceGroupName, Name 

    $AI | foreach { 
    write-output ("Attempting to set daily cap for App Insights in resource group {0} instance {1}" -f $_.ResourceGroupName, $_.Name)
    Set-AzureRmApplicationInsightsDailyCap -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName -Name $_.Name -DailyCapGB 0.2 

    }
}

Set-DailyCap
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a modified version of @RonDBA's solution, which includes some logic to parse the names and set limits based on their name. Using this script, I was able to update hundreds of daily caps in a matter of seconds.

```
import-module azurerm.applicationinsights

Login-AzureRmAccount
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionName "yoursubscription here"

$ai = Get-AzureRmApplicationInsights | select ResourceGroupName, Name

$AI | foreach {
    $cap = 1
    $color = 'red'
    if($_.Name -match 'dev'){
        $cap = .12
        $color = 'green'
    }
    if($_.Name -match 'stg'){
        $cap = .24
        $color = 'blue'
    }
    if($cap -eq 1)
    {
        if($_.Name -match 'api'){
            $cap = 1.4
            $color = 'yellow'
        }
        else{$cap = 2.9}
    }
    
    write-host ("Attempting to set daily cap at $cap for {0} instance " -f $_.ResourceGroupName) -NoNewline
    write-host $_.Name -ForegroundColor $color
    Set-AzureRmApplicationInsightsDailyCap -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName -Name $_.Name -DailyCapGB $cap
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can change the daily cap of your application insights component using Azure CLI or even Azure REST APIs as of today.

> To change it, use the **Daily volume cap blade**, linked from the Data
>   Volume Management blade (see below). Note that some subscription types
>   have credit which cannot be used for Application Insights. If the
>   subscription has a spending limit, the daily cap blade will have
>   instructions how to remove it and enable the daily cap to be raised
>   beyond 32.3 MB/day.

[image]

**Data source/Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-pricing#data-rate

Comment: this manual solution is not much suitable for bigger amount resources. (~50 in my case). Hope that we can see some better option soon. Like CLI or REST API.

Comment: Especially as the default seems to be 500GB/day (which if left as such can cost you a lot of money at ~2$ per GB)
With our Infrastructure as Code when (re)building we need to manually change this. We recently had an issue with a misconfiguration on a test environment, and it kept reporting socket exceptions to AppInsights, at a rate of 150GB/day. It took us a few days to notice the logs and huge cost in AI. :-(

Comment: as of November 2017, [at least the powershell cmdlets have been updated](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/18792571-ability-to-get-and-set-billing-properties-basic-e)