# Azure CLI - limit resource daily data volume

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-cli

I'm using **application insights** with **Azure CLI** commands, I'm looking to limit resource daily data volume (**daily cap**) with Azure CLI commands but I can't found any tutorial / idea how to do it wit h az commands.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Currently, there is no way you can change the daily cap of your application insights component using Azure CLI.

However, you can change the daily cap with the Azure PowerShell cmdlet [Set-AzureRmApplicationInsightsDailyCap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.applicationinsights/set-azurermapplicationinsightsdailycap?view=azurermps-6.13.0).
Example:

```
Set-AzureRmApplicationInsightsDailyCap -ResourceGroupName "testgroup" -Name "test" -DailyCapGB 400
 -DisableNotificationWhenHitCap

 Cap ResetTime StopSendNotificationWhenHitCap
--- --------- ------------------------------
400         0                           True
```

You could get more details from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941977/azure-application-insights-how-to-change-daily-cap-by-azure-cli/45943374#45943374) and this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/18792571-ability-to-get-and-set-billing-properties-basic-e). If you want to improve this, you could also give your voice in [Azure feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights).